# Running mpi with C# programs on OS X

Tags: c#, mpi, mpich

I tried running an mpi program written in C# on OSX, however, I keep getting the permission denied error.
The steps I took to install mpi:

- installed homebrew
- using homebrew installed mpich
- installed mono (so I can get a .exe file)
- created a project in Rider, specified target frameworks to be net50 (latest .net core) and net48 (assume provided by mono)
- installed mpi.net nuget package
- went into the Debug directory of net48 containing ConsoleApp1.exe
- ran the command `mpirun -np 4 ./ConsoleApp1.exe` with and without sudo

However, I get the following error:

```
[proxy:0:0@Marins-MacBook-Pro.local] HYDU_create_process (utils/launch/launch.c:74): execvp error on file ./ConsoleApp1.exe (Permission denied)
```

The error is repeated once for each process.

Using finder I selected the exe file and parent folder in question and gave everyone permissions to read and write (read permissions are granted by default). However, the problem still persists.

What can I try to solve this issue?

EDIT:
I also tried with the following command:

```
mpiexec -n 4 mono ConsoleApp1.exe
```

However, I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: msmpi.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MPI.Unsafe.MPI_Finalized(int&)
  at MPI.Environment.get_Finalized () [0x00000] in <fa7716c2d3a447518b7b229d8fa8506f>:0 
  at MPI.Environment..ctor (System.String[]& args, MPI.Threading threading) [0x00006] in <fa7716c2d3a447518b7b229d8fa8506f>:0 
  at MPI.Environment..ctor (System.String[]& args) [0x00000] in <fa7716c2d3a447518b7b229d8fa8506f>:0 
  at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in <4afb3f1ea5bc4367a9a7afd6da6576a3>:0
```

I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to use mpi on OS X.

Comment: are you able to simply run `./ConsoleApp1.exe`?

Comment: the error message is about `msmpi` (Microsoft MPI?) but you are using MPICH's `mpirun`.

Comment: I was unable to find a microsoft msmpi distribution for a platform other than windows. I assumed mpich or open-mpi would work...

Comment: Right there in [the package description](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPI.NET/), is says: _"This NuGet package is for Windows only. **The MPI.NET code works on Linux, but needs to be compiled on the target platform. This package is compiled for use with Microsoft's msmpi.dll (Windows HPC).** Migration to .NET Standard 2.0."_